# SQL datetime issue with group by clause

Tags: sql-server

Below is my query which does not returns last 6 months data properly, because i have changed my datetime format. I want to maintain my format of the date

```
select InventoryGroup,
    ProjectId,
    SubscriptionGuid,
    SUM(extendedcost) as Cost,
    RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date], 105), 7) as [YearMonth]
from CostDetails
group by InventoryGroup,
    ProjectId,
    SubscriptionGuid,
    RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date], 105), 7)
having InventoryGroup <> ''
    and (
        RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date], 105), 7) > RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DATEADD(m, - 6, GETDATE())), 0), 105), 7)
        or RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date], 105), 7) = RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE() - 1, 105), 7)
        )
```

Below is my current output

[image]

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Why don't you just let the presentation layer format the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing the whole problem is caused by using `having` clause instead of `where`. Maybe this would work better:

```
select InventoryGroup,
    ProjectId,
    SubscriptionGuid,
    SUM(extendedcost) as Cost,
    RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date], 105), 7) as [YearMonth]
from CostDetails
where InventoryGroup <> '' and 
    [Date] > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DATEADD(m, - 6, GETDATE())), 0)
group by InventoryGroup,
    ProjectId,
    SubscriptionGuid,
    RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date], 105), 7)
```

Left this out, because isn't this the previous statement always true (newer than past 6 months), if it's month of yesterday:

```
or RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date], 105), 7) = RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE() - 1, 105), 7)
```